# Tomcat default folder in ubuntu to keep Java applications

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am new user at Ubuntu 14.04. I had installed tomcat 7 on Ubuntu. I want to put my Java application context in default folder of tomcat 7. So where I can put context and how can I run that context?

Comment: Tomcat+deployment http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

Comment: Not getting clearly can you explain by some examples ? Can you tell me the steps ?